# Swift: How to get image name from assets

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I have 500mb of images in folders in assets. I don't know any of their names. Is there a way to access them...store them to Array and then display?

Example: I have 3 images stored in `Assets/folder1/folder2`
folder 2 contains that 3 images..... I need to get those names.

[image]

Here is the reason I need this.... Ive been provided with library of car images and that images have illogical names.

[image]

Comment: Are these images stored in the application bundle of a mac or iOS app? Or are they stored on the disk?

Comment: You "have" them but you don't know their names? How can that be?

Comment: I need to access them in app by code.

Comment: You say: "Example: I have 3 images stored in Assets/folder1/folder2" What is "Assets" and where is it? Is this some sort of shorthand for the asset catalog? Or is it an actual folder called Assets, in your app bundle?

Comment: Updated question with image

Comment: Why don't you give the images better names?

Comment: Well thats option also... I just want to try solve it this way....the harsh way is to rename them.

Comment: Why is it harsh? You are a programmer! This is a two-line script. Easy. Or use Automator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you are describing while storing the images in the Assets Catalog. Fetching a resource from an Assets Catalog relies upon your knowing its actual name.

Instead, store these folders directly at the top level of your app bundle. Now you have an actual folder that you can get a reference to, and can ask the FileManager for the names of the images in the folder.

[image]

Example (Swift 2.2, sorry):

```
let f = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("carPix", withExtension: nil)!
let fm = NSFileManager()
let arr = try! fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(f, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
print(arr) // the URLs of the two jpg files
```

Comment: oh.... what do u mean by FileManager? I don't want to rightclick every picture to get its path... i have 3000+ images with size of 510 Mb :-/

Comment: Check out this: http://imgur.com/a/Gz5Y9 .... this is the structure that I must work with.

Answer (score 0):

Example above with Swift 3

```
if let f = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "carPix", withExtension: nil) {
    let fm = FileManager()
    return try? fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: f, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
}
return nil
```